# Django user doesn't inherit its groups permissions

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-users

In my Django project my jack user is in a group called 'Personals'. 'Personals' group has a permission named 'personal'. But jack doesn't inherit that permission from its group. Jack user doesn't have the 'personal' permission which its groups have. Why jack user didn't take the permission from its group?

```
>>>jack = User.objects.get(username="jack")
>>>jack_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=jack)
>>>print(jack_permissions)
<QuerySet []>   #It gives a emty query.

>>>jack_group = jack.groups.all()
>>>print(jack_group)
Personals
>>>jacks_group = Group.objects.get(name="Personals")
>>>jacks_groups_permissions = jacks_group.permissions.all()
>>>print(jacks_groups_permissions)
<QuerySet [<Permission: auth | user | The Personals>]>      #The Group has the permission The Personals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`User.get_all_permissions()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions) to get all permissions that the user has including permissions inherited from groups or use [`User.get_group_permissions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_group_permissions) to get all permissions that a user has from their groups

```
jack_permissions = jack.get_all_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your many-to-one relation chain is like the following:

`User > Group > Permission`

And you want to get all permissions related to a particular user. If so, you can use double-underscore (`__`) notation to get the through relationship.

Does this get you what you want?

```py
jack = User.objects.get(username="jack")
jack_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(group__users=jack)
```

Comment: I am using groups because I want to every user in this group have the groups permissions. Isn't this how to use groups?